# Is the category of measurable spaces MONOIDAL closed? (fake-proof)

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, category-theory, fake-proofs, measurable-functions

As discussed on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/223504/142698), there is a [preprint on ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6030v4) that claims the category of measurable spaces is monoidal closed (in particular that exponential objects $Y^X$ always exist and have measurable evaluation maps $X \times Y^X \to Y$).

Also [as discussed in the same post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1388/is-there-a-natural-measures-on-the-space-of-measurable-functions/28114#comment866999_223504), such a claim appears to contradict [results by Robert Aumann](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28114/142698) that exponential objects do not always exist in the category of measurable spaces (i.e. there exists no $\sigma$-algebra on $Y^X$ for which the evaluation map $X \times Y^X \to Y$ is measurable). So the claim is likely to be false.

I have been scrutinizing the preprint and I think I may have identified the error in the argument. Am I correct? Or is the claim actually true?

**High-level overview of my argument:** Because $\sigma$-algebras are only closed under countable operations, rather than arbitrary ones, it is easier for $\sigma$-algebras that make all members of a certain class of functions measurable to not exist? (And therefore easier for there to not be any initial or final $\sigma$-algebras generated by those functions?) Cf. [this comment on the MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1388/is-there-a-natural-measures-on-the-space-of-measurable-functions/28114#comment839869_120736).

I.e. in contrast to the situation with topologies, which are closed under arbitrary unions, which makes it easier to guarantee that there always exists *some* topology for which a collection of functions is measurable? (Thus allowing the existence of initial or final topologies.)

**Details of attempted disproof:** The main issue seems to be that the preprint uses a non-standard definition for the $\sigma$-algebra on the Cartesian product of two measurable spaces $X \times Y$ when defining the monoidal product $X \otimes Y$:

> The coinduced (final) $\sigma$-algebra [on $X \times Y$] such that all graph functions
> $$\begin{array}{rccl}
>  \Gamma_f: & X  &\to & X \times Y \\
> & x & \mapsto & (x, f(x))
>  \end{array}$$
> for $f: X \to Y$ measurable, as well as all the graph functions
> $$\begin{array}{rccl}
>  \Gamma_g: & Y  &\to & X \times Y \\
> & y & \mapsto & (g(y), y)
>  \end{array}$$
> for $g: Y \to X$ measurable, are measurable.

**Main question**: The above $\sigma$-algebra isn't even guaranteed to exist in general, correct?

**Asides/extra questions/comments:**
Normally the product $\sigma$-algebra would be defined as the induced (initial) $\sigma$-algebra such that the projections $(x,y) \mapsto x$ and $(x,y) \mapsto y$ are measurable, right?

In particular the definition from the preprint, and the standard definition, are not always equivalent, correct? (*As an aside, are they ever equivalent?*)

I can go into the details of how the preprint then defines the initial topology on $Y^X$ generated by the pointwise projections/evaluations, and from there the argument for why the evaluation map $X \otimes Y^X = X \times Y^X \to Y$ is measurable, but if the above topology isn't even guaranteed to exist, then the argument definitely seems to fail. (With [Robert Aumann providing a counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28114/142698) in the case that $X = Y = [0,1]$.)

**Terminology:** By "initial $\sigma$-algebra" on $X$ generated by functions $f_{\alpha}: X \to Y$, with $Y$ a measurable space, I mean the "coarsest" or "smallest" possible $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ such that all of the $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ are measurable.

By "final $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ generated by functions $f_{\alpha}: X \to Y$, with $X$ a measurable space, I mean the "finest" or "largest" possible $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ such that all of the $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ are measurable. (I guess technically one could also require that $\{f_{\beta}\}$ for $f_{\beta}: X_2 \to Y$ are measurable for $X_2$ a measurable space, which is what the preprint appears to do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coinduced/final $\sigma$-algebra here is in fact guaranteed to exist in general.
It is constructed analogously to the [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology).

In particular, suppose we have some set $V$ on which we wish to define the final $\sigma$-algebra.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote a collection of functions $f : U_f \to V$, where $U_f$ is part of a measurable space $(U_f, \Sigma_{U_f})$, which we emphasise may vary depending on $f$.
The final $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_V$ is the largest $\sigma$-algebra that makes each $f \in \mathcal{F}$ measurable.
Explicitly, $B \in \Sigma_V$ iff $f^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma_{U_f}$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

To see that this is a $\sigma$-algebra, for each $f \in \mathcal{F}$, if we denote
$$
\Delta_{f} := \{B \subseteq V : f^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma_{U_f} \},
$$
then we can write
$$
\Sigma_V = \bigcap_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Delta_f.
$$
But now it is [easily checked](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pre-Image_Sigma-Algebra_on_Codomain_is_Sigma-Algebra) that each $\Delta_f$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and hence $\Sigma_V$ is too.

In the case that interests you, take $V = X \times Y$, and let $\mathcal{F}$ consist of all graph functions $X \to X \times Y$ and $Y \to X \times Y$.
I'm not sure if the final $\sigma$-algebra on $X \times Y$ defined here is different to the usual product $\sigma$-algebra (which you are right is usually taken to be *initial* with respect to the projection maps), but I suspect this is the case. If so, then there is not necessarily a contradiction between Sturtz's work and Aumann's, since these would be talking about different monoidal products.